# How do I program a batch file to choose desktop wallpaper based on screen resolution?

Tags: batch-file, wallpaper

How do I program a batch file to check what the screens resolution is then pull the corresponding size wallpaper from a shared drive and set it as the wallpaper?

Comment: You may want to update the title of the question to cover what you actually want to ask - it is too generic and unsearchable currently.

Answer (score 1):

To get the screen resolution from the command line check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/270718/get-display-resolution-from-windows-command-line).  Once you figure out this use [this article](http://www.windows-commandline.com/change-windows-wallpaper-command-line/) to change the wallpaper from the command line.